# Reference counting Java

Tags: java

Какие недостатки имеет метод reference counting при обнаружении мусора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Reference counting
```

Суть подхода состоит в том, что каждый объект имеет счетчик. Счетчик хранит информацию о том, сколько ссылок указывает на объект. Kогда ссылка уничтожается, счетчик уменьшается. Если значение счетчика равно нулю, - объект можно считать мусором и память можно очищать.

Главным минусом такого подхода является сложность обеспечения точности счетчика. Также при таком подходе сложно выявлять циклические зависимости (когда два объекта указывают друг на друга, но ни один живой объект на них не ссылается). Это приводит к утечкам памяти.

Comment: Что значит формулировка: "но ни один живой объект на них не ссылается"?

Comment: @bsuart `SomeClass a = new SomeClass(); SomeClass b = a; a = null;` Т.е. были две ссылки на один экземпляр класса, потом одну занулили, и при этом вторая тоже стала равна null. Данное поведение очень сложно отследить